# Keep URL after Trailing slash by preserving URL parameters using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Due to usage of relative URL, somehow Google Crawler has wrongly indexed our site. 
After a thourough analysis of the indexed URLs in Google, we have come to the conclusion that we should redirect URLs  by taking the sections after the Trailing Slash with some exceptions. We have therefore tried to put below many of these URLs and how they should be redirected to.

```
 /a.php/ - Redirect to /a.php
   /a.php// - Redirect to /a.php
   /a.php - Retain as it is
   /a.html - Retain as it is
   /a.php/a.html - Redirect to /a.html
   /a.php/b.php?a=b - Redirect to /b.php?a=b
   /a.html/b.php - Redirect to /b.php
   /a.html/b.php/c.html - Redirect to /c.html
   /a.php/b.php?a=b/c.php?a=b - Redirect to /c.php?a=b
   /a.html/b.php - Redirect to /b.php
```

Please note that /index.php is already redirected to www.domain.com
Could you help in providing us with a htaccess code that we can use to achieve these redirection

Comment: You need to show what you've tried already.

Comment: we tried some code that did not work. Unfortunately I do not have this code snippet. But I remember it was only able to delete the trailing slash. All in all it was not usefull.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
# This should match the first two
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/[^/]+)(/+) HTTP/1\.[01]$
RewriteRule .* %1 [L,R=301]

# This should match the rest, without matching /a.php and /a.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+ /[^/]+ HTTP/1\.[01]$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+ (/[^/]+)?(/[^/]+)(/[^/]+) HTTP/1\.[01]$
RewriteRule .* %3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: should this be placed in the begining of the htaccess file

Comment: That depends what else is in your htaccess file, can you provide your full htaccess file so I can confirm the correct location? And to make sure none of the rules clash?

Comment: I tried loading this into the htaccess but getting 500 server error. Also tried doing it in parts but still getting error. looks like there are min. 2 errors. Could you help please. If you like I can also share my contact in skype

Comment: I need to see your full htaccess to be able to help. Either add it to your question or provide a link to a text-sharing website eg pastebin.com

Comment: how do i share that. can you provide mail address or connect me on skype. In fact I cannot share also in this thread as there are full urls which posting rule wont allow me to upload. If you are OK, it will be very helpfull if we can speak in skype. if you agree I can share. Thanks

Comment: ok I understood how you wanted me to share. sorry. the file name is details.txt and the site is goo.gl/sB7EKq    please check and let me know

Comment: Ok, thanks, try putting my rules as the first rules after "RewriteEngine On" and if you get a 500 internal server error, please provide the error message from your error log.

Comment: No actually this did not work. sorry. Therefore I have adopted a alternate method , although not so good but will suffice